# Problem accessing database from front end of a component

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, development, mysql, custom-component

I am currently working on a component which will display "events", stored in a database, on a map (filterable by location, category, date etc...). My first step is to display a simple report of the database, in a table. However, I am struggling to populate the html table with the values stored in my sql table. Any ideas where i am going wrong? From what i understand, Joomla requires a model, view, and controller. Here is my code for each:

**com_filteredMap/site/models/filteredmap.php**

```
    <?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

/**
 * FilteredMapList Model
 *
 * @since  0.0.1
 */
class FilteredMapModelFilteredMap extends JModelList
{
    /**
     * Method to build an SQL query to load the list data.
     *
     * @return      string  An SQL query
     */
    protected function getListQuery()
    {
        // Initialize variables.
        $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Create the base select statement.
        $query->select('*')
                ->from($db->quoteName('#__filteredmap'));

        return $query;
    }
}
```

**com_filteredMap/site/views/filteredmap/view.html.php**

```
<?php
class FilteredMapViewFilteredMap extends JViewLegacy
{
    /**
     * Display the Filtered map view
     *
     * @param   string  $tpl  The name of the template file to parse; automatically searches through the template paths.
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        // Assign data to the view
        $this->item = $this->get('Item');
        $this->pagination   = $this->get('Pagination');

        // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
        {
            JLog::add(implode('<br />', $errors), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');

            return false;
        }

        // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

**com_filteredMap/site/controller.php**

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
/**
 * Filtered Map Component Controller
 *
 * @since  0.0.1
 */
class FilteredMapController extends JControllerLegacy
{
        /**
     * Proxy for getModel.
     *
     * @param   string  $name    The model name. Optional.
     * @param   string  $prefix  The class prefix. Optional.
     * @param   array   $config  Configuration array for model. Optional.
     *
     * @return  object  The model.
     *
     * @since   1.6
     */
    public function getModel($name = 'FilteredMap', $prefix = 'FilteredMapModel', $config = array('ignore_request' => true))
    {
        $model = parent::getModel($name, $prefix, $config);

        return $model;
    }
}
```

**com_filteredMap/site/views/filteredmap/tmpl/default.php**

```
    <?php

// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
?>
<h1> Filtered Map </h1>

<form method="post" id="frontEndForm" name="frontEndForm">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="84%">
                <?php echo JText::_('Event Sumary') ;?>
            </th>
            <th width="6%">
                <?php echo JText::_('Date'); ?>
            </th>
            <th width="10%">
                <?php echo JText::_('Location'); ?>            
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
                <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <?php //echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <?php if (!empty($this->items)) : ?>
                <?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $row) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row->title; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row->dates; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php //addlocationhere ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

The above code causes the following to be displayed:

[image: screenshot of extension's front end page]

I have worked with Joomla for a while but i am fairly new to programming extensions. Any help/advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall this is coming along well!

You just need to change in your view.html.php

```
$this->item = $this->get('Item');
```

to

```
$this->items = $this->get('Items');
```

This call will get translated by the view `get` function into a call `getItems` in the model JModelList, which will then run the query you supplied in your model `getListQuery`.

You're already iterating through `$this->items` properly in your layout file.